# Performance issue with varchar2 2000 byte column in oracle

Tags: performance, oracle, varchar2

i have a column that is varchar2 (2000 bytes), this is an existing column and is being used in many places, the issue is when i am trying to compare with this column the query is taking 30-40 seconds to execute. the query is as simple as below-

```
select response_id from t_response where desc_response = to_char(1000);
```

`desc_response` is that column.

i found that we have only one index as of now on this table and that is on response_id column.

Answer (score 2):

> "we have only one index as of now on this table and that is on response_id column."

So your query is executing a full table scan, reading every record in the table to inspect the value of `desc_response`.

You neglected to say how many rows the table has but this is *simple physics*.  Tables with lots of rows take longer to search.  So on the  basis of 30-40 seconds, I guess this is a big table.

Build an index on `desc_response` and the execution time will drop.  By how much depends on all sorts of factors.